# Mongoose SELECT on nested schema (select: false)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to select information from a nested schema. The information is excluded by default as `select: false` is specified.

```
var ASchema = new Schema({
  property: {
    type: String,
      select: false // !! Note here!!
  }
};

[...]

var BSchema = new Schema({
  a: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ASchema'
  }
});

[...]

BModel.findById([someIdHere]).select({
  'a': 1,
  'a.property': 1 // !! Does not work as expected!!
}).exec(function(err, b) {
  if(err) return;
  console.log(b); // b does not include a.property!!
});
```

If anyone could enlighten me on how I can select `property` in the query, it would be great.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417150/mongoose-nested-documents

Comment: @Damodaran That post doesn't have any properties which are excluded from the query on default.

Comment: It seems that I've answered my own question. At http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, see under "Query conditions and other options".