# how to get recursively all objects attached to a model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested

imagine these two nested mongoose models, a **Vote** containing a list of **Candidates**

```js
    var candidateSchema = new Schema({
        name: String
    });

    var voteSchema = new Schema({
        candidates: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Candidate' }]
    });

    voteSchema.methods.addCandidate = function addCandidate(newCandidate, callback) {
        this.candidates.addToSet(newCandidate);
        this.save(callback);
    };

    var Vote = mongoose.model('Vote', voteSchema);
    var vote = new Vote();

    var Candidate = mongoose.model('Candidate', candidateSchema);
    var candidate = new Candidate({ name: 'Guillaume Vincent' });
    vote.addCandidate(candidate);

    console.log(vote); // { _id: 53d613fdadfd08d9ebea6f88, candidates: [ 53d68476fc78cb55f5d91c17] }
    console.log(vote.toJSON()); // { _id: 53d613fdadfd08d9ebea6f88, candidates: [ 53d68476fc78cb55f5d91c17] }
```

If I use `candidates: [candidateSchema]` instead of `candidates: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Candidate' }]` then `console.log(vote);` display :

```js
{
    _id: 53d613fdadfd08d9ebea6f88, 
    candidates: [ { _id: 53d613fdadfd08d9ebea6f86, name: 'Guillaume Vincent' } ] 
}
```

My question is :

With `candidates: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Candidate' }]` how can I get recursively all objects attached to a model ? same behavior with `candidates: [candidateSchema]`

I'm not using embedded schema because I want my Vote to be updated when I update my Candidate (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418739/866886)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Mongoose's support for [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

For example:

```
Vote.find().populate('candidates').exec(callback);
```

will populate the `candidates` array with the full `Candidate` object for each id.